RN The official scaffolding project introduced bundlejs and modified it again, but the hot update could not be triggered

Introduced in app.tsx. official scaffolding、official scaffolding、official scaffolding、official scaffolding


const infos = require('./infos')



const App = () => {

  <View>

  <<infos />
</view>
}
     
export default App;

``   

2. Modify file A and cannot trigger hot.

3. I would like to ask how to trigger my bundlejs file through metro and trigger hot update again.

4. Thank you very much.

